# Get rid of the TreeViewItem Expander from ComboBox's SelectedItemBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

I have a comboBox with list of TreeViewItems.
Now, every time I select a TreeViewItem, the SelectedItemBox of the ComboBox shows the expander of the TreeViewItem that has been selected from the drop-down.

[image: see the arrow on the SelectedItemBox of the comboBox]

How can I stop the expander from showing up in the SelectedItem box??

Thanks!

Comment: why do you want treeviewitem in combobox?

Comment: i meant are you showing heirarichal data in your combobox?

Comment: what do you mean UI Requirement? It seems like your requirement is that it does not behave like a treeview....

Comment: I am showing hierarchial data in my combo box...so the contents of my combo box have to be tree-view items, but i want the displayed selected-item to only be a string...